# using jquery set datepicker value to "" on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datepicker

I have a jsp code which on submit calls this function

```
function filterExcessPage() {
    setDefaultValues();
    var fromLast =document.getElementById('fromLast').value;
    var fromDate =document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
    var toDate =document.getElementById('toDate').value;
    $("#excessListForm").submit(function() {
        if((toDate.length>0) && (fromDate.length==0)) { 
            $('#validateDate').text('*from date is mandatory');
            return false;
        }else if ((fromDate.length>0) && (new Date(fromDate)>new Date())) {
            $('#validateDate').text('*from date should be less than current date');
            excessListForm.fromDate.value="";
            return false;
        }else if ((toDate.length>0) && (new Date(toDate)>new Date())) {
            $('#validateDate').text('*to Date should be less than current date');
            excessListForm.toDate.value="";
            return false;
        }else {
            var queryUrl = "/excessManagement.web/inbox.htm?excessFilteredData=true&fromLast=" + fromLast+"&fromDate="+fromDate+"&toDate="+toDate;
            excessListForm.action =  queryUrl;
            excessListForm.submit();
        }
    });

}

function setDefaultValues() {
    excessListForm.cif.value="";
    excessListForm.customerName.value="";
    excessListForm.fromLast.value="";
    excessListForm.fromDate.value="";
    excessListForm.toDate.value="";     
}
```

The fromdate and todate values reappear on form submission....
After form submission the values displayed in fromdate,todate textboxes are in the format i am using in my java class ....
I need to set the values to "" after form submission...

Comment: Set the value in client side

Answer (score 0):

set in client side

```
  var fromDate =document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
    var toDate =document.getElementById('toDate').value;

fromDate.value= "";
toDate.value =""
```

Comment: When you perform formsubmit, from the Client side put this code, this will work. it basic html/javascript code

Comment: On server side,after returning response, i added it and it is working...For client side,I think setDefaultValues() function in the above code is meant to do the same but....i added it before excessListForm.submit(); statement...even then it was not working